# PySpark: data doesn't always conform to schema - logic to alter data

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm new with PySpark and am working on a script, reading from `.csv` files.

I've explicitly defined the schema in the below & the script works perfectly...most of the time.

The issue is, on occasion, a value enters the files which does not conform to the schema - e.g. '-' might appear in an integer field & hence, we get a type error - the error is thrown when `df1.show()` is reached in the script.

I'm trying to think of a way to effectively say - if the value does not match the defined datatype, then replace with ''

Does anyone know if this may be possible? Any advice would be great!

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as sqlfunc
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import argparse, sys
from pyspark.sql import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from datetime import datetime
#create a context that supports hive
def create_session(appname):
    spark_session = SparkSession\
        .builder\
        .appName(appname)\
        .master('yarn')\
        .config("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://serverip:9083")\
        .enableHiveSupport()\
        .getOrCreate()
    return spark_session

### START MAIN ###
if __name__ == '__main__':
    spark_session = create_session('testing_files')
    dt_now = datetime.now()

    today_unixtime = long(dt_now.strftime('%s'))
    today_date = datetime.fromtimestamp(today_unixtime).strftime('%Y%m%d')

    twoday_unixtime = long(dt_now.strftime('%s')) - 24*60*60*2
    twoday = datetime.fromtimestamp(twoday_unixtime).strftime('%Y%m%d')

    hourago = long(dt_now.strftime('%s')) - 60*60*4
    hrdate = datetime.fromtimestamp(hourago).strftime('%H')

    schema = [\
        StructField('field1', StringType(), True),\
        StructField('field2',StringType(), True), \
        StructField('field3',IntegerType(), True) \
        ]
    final_structure = StructType(schema)

    df1 = spark_session.read\
        .option("header","false")\
        .option("delimiter", "\t")\
        .csv('hdfs://hdfspath/dt=%s/*/*/*' %today_date, final_structure)

    usercatschema = [\
        StructField('field1', StringType(), True),\
        StructField('field2',StringType(), True), \
        StructField('field3',StringType(), True) \
        ]
    usercat_structure = StructType(usercatschema)

    df2 = spark_session.read\
        .option("header","false")\
        .option("delimiter", "\t")\
        .csv('hdfs://hdfspath/v0/dt=%s/*' %twoday, usercat_structure)

    df1.show()
    df2.show()
    df1.createOrReplaceTempView("dpi")
    df2.createOrReplaceTempView("usercat")

    finaldf = spark_session.sql('''
    SQL QUERY
''')
    finaldf.coalesce(10).write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").option('sep', '\t').mode('append').save('hdfs://hdfs path')
```

Comment: read it as StringType then cast that column to int

Comment: Simple but brilliant. Thank you for the advice - I'll have a go now. How can I mark a comment as the right answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read it as String type and then convert to int.

```
df.withColumn("field3",df.field3.cast("int"))
```